# electron store data -> read/write from/to json file on network drive

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm currently working on a small electron application that is meant to be installed on all local machines in our firm and should be able to read/write 
to our shared network drive.

So far I have been using [electron-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store) because of its simplicity.
I'm very new to electron (or nodejs for that matter) development and electron-store gives me a nice and easy way to store data.

So what I'm looking for exactly is:

A way (or node module) to store data locally (as it's default with electron-store) **as well as** store data (preferabley the same way) on a network drive.

I'd like to organize all data inside an object and save/read to/from .json.

You think that is possible with electron-store, cause I couldn't figure it out?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!